# How to facilitate the export of secret strings from an offline system?

Tags: secret-sharing

I want to use Shamir's Secret Sharing algorithm to store a randomly generated passphrase securely by spreading the secret shares on paper for example.

The passphrase is generated on an offline system. I am looking for a way to ease the process of "exporting" those secrets which can be quite long (~100 hexadecimal characters).

First I converted the secrets from hexadecimal to base64. That is not bad but not enough.

Then I tried to compress the strings using different methods but because it is random data it does not compress well (or at all).

Then I though of printing them as QR code, it works fine but the issue comes later when I need to import the secrets back, because I would need a camera.

Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "easing" the process? Do you want the secrets to be compressed in length? Do you want them to be easier to remember or  input (e.g. type down with less typos)?

Comment: They do not have to be easy to remember because they will be written on paper or other physical/offline storage. It is more about length and typos, although typos can be aleviated by other methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have found yourself, [random strings, especially cryptographic secure ones, cannot usually be compressed](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/51930/57767).

If you are mostly worried about typos, and you can accept an increase in length, you could use a wordlist approach, for example using [the PGP word list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGP_word_list) or [the S/KEY dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/KEY).

Alternatively, you could opt for bar codes. They don't require a proper "camera" in the traditional sense of the word. Using this approach, you would simply buy one (or more) barcode readers and use them to read the secrets from a piece of paper.